# How to have a h1, p and an img on the same line but have my h1 center

Tags: html, css

I want my h1 to be centered but the 'text-align' doesn't work. My p and my img are on the same line but they are not on the same line of my h1. Do I need to manually move pixel by pixel to center my H1 ? why aren't they on the same line if I have the same display set?

```css
.nav {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0;
  line-height: 18px;
  background-color: #7D1935;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav h1 {
  color: #F5F3EE;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
.nav p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #F5F3EE;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
}
.nav img {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <img src="http://fr.locita.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/facebook-logo1.jpg" height="30" width="30">
    </a>

    <p>stuff</p>

    <h1>text here</h1>


  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ohtysfg6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `text-align: center` from `h1` to `.nav` and it works:

```css
.nav {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0;
  line-height: 18px;
  background-color: #7D1935;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav h1 {
  color: #F5F3EE;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**Preview**

[image]

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ohtysfg6/4/**

Comment: ohhhhhh! Now i look foolish! Thanks for the help!